# What is the best Apache logs Analyzer?

Tags: apache, analytics, logging

**What real-time log analyzer can you suggest for Apache access and error logs?**

There is a [list of web analytics software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software) on WikiPedia, but it would be great to hear opinions from people with experience without having to try all of them.

Please don't suggest Google Analytics or any other hosted/JavaScript analytics suites, already using them, GA is not real-time and it is missing some data that the logs show. For example 404 errors, script errors, the full query-string of the referral, IP addresses, visitor path through the website, etc ...

Comment: can this be turned into community-wiki?

Comment: Real time log analysis is waay different than real time JS-based tracking.  The former is difficult to implement and doesn't scale across multiple instances, and the latter is what Google Analytics uses.

If you're looking for a solid Apache logs analyzer, check out Angelfish.
http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/

Comment: I disagree with the policy of banning all opinion based questions.  In many cases an opinion is valuable information, especially if the writer has used more than one product. Rather than ban them, opinion based questions should be flagged as such, and answers held to a different standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using Urchin before I switched to Google Analyics. The Urchin Project no longer exists.

Comment: didn't know urchin could analyze logs -- but it can! this is great!

Comment: only downside is that it costs a fortune :/

Comment: Too bad there's no community edition or open source equivalent...

Comment: Urchin has been discontinued.

Comment: This is the new alternative to Urchin (open source!) http://piwik.org/log-analytics/

Comment: For log analysis, we replaced Urchin with Angelfish:
http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/

Comment: Google Analytics *is* Urchin, at least the javascript-based Urchin On Demand portion.  After purchasing the Urchin company, Google Analytics killed the server side version.

Comment: @zylstra Because of course they did. :)

Answer (score 61):

[GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/) is a free text/curses based log analyzer similar to "top".

[image: GoAccess main scrollable dashboard]

Comment: Nice... CentOS even has it in its default repo.

Comment: it would be great it you could share the centos repo!

Answer (score 13):

[AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a good open source solution.

Also see http://www.awstats.org and https://github.com/eldy/awstats

Comment: doesn't support nginx

Comment: AWStats supports Apache log format, and nginx can easily output in Apache log format, so...  it does support nginx indirectly.

Comment: Tried this. It can tell you what pages were viewed, and it can tell you who visited and when, and if you need to find out which visitor or IP has been methodically working through your site loading page after page as if they're looking for a vulnerability... go fish, because Awstats won't tell you, near as I can figure out. Or, someone's been repeatedly visiting my site from Google.hk search results, want to know who or what they searched? Tough luck. Blech.

Answer (score 11):

[Matomo](https://matomo.org/) (former Piwik) is a good choice (better than awstats, in my opinion)

Comment: This is the right link for "Log Analyzer" feature of Piwik: http://piwik.org/log-analytics/

Comment: Note: piwik requires that a javascript pixel be added to all your pages.

Comment: Not necessarily Jay, you can also make Piwik/Matomo crawl your logs. The official manual to do this can be found at https://matomo.org/docs/log-analytics-tool-how-to/

Answer (score 5):

This might seem like a bit of overkill, but **[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)** offers web log analyzing and *much, much* more.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an offline analyzer, I quite like Sawmill:

https://www.sawmill.co.uk

It analyses all sorts of logs, including apache. Has a free trial period.

Comment: You have to pay for this...

Answer (score 1):

[ChartBeat](https://chartbeat.com) a very interesting service, it is actually much more than log analyst - more like a view of the buzz your blog creates, in real-time. 
Another tool that shows real-time Apache log streams I found, called [A Live Log](http://www.burlaca.com/2009/02/alivelog/).