# Is there anything better than awstats?

Tags: server, monitoring, awstats, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best Apache logs Analyzer?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4852/what-is-the-best-apache-logs-analyzer)

I am looking for something to do some basic apache log analysis server side, or remotely. awstats seems like it has all the info, but its too much, and it is so ugly. Isn't there some zero config, zero maintenance options out there to do simple server log analysis other than awstat?

Comment: What kind of information are you after? I've used Apache's mod_status module with Zenoss or Nagios for some basic metrics.

Comment: Just the basics - top page hits, browseruser-agent/os breakdowns, hourly hit histograms

Answer (score 0):

> zero config, zero maintenance

You won't get much for nothing.

Have a look at [Google Analytic](http://www.google.com/analytics/)s or [PiWik](http://piwik.org/)