# Google Analitycs says source is Search Engine (100%)

Tags: optimization, google-analytics

I have a problem with my google analytics code, 'cause it says since 2 months that all traffic of my websites is directly from search engine, i'm really sure that must be a mistake 'cause i have made some email marketing and landing page campaing that could help to create referal traffic, maybe somethink goes wrong with the new version of the analytics or i forgot some settings. please any help is aceptable

Comment: Can you structure this in the form of a question? It is difficult to see what is being asked here.

Comment: If you're using the standard GA tracking code and haven't modified it, it will be correct.  If you've modified it, it would be a good idea to post what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to them, check your server logs. [Heres a question about apache log analyzer software](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4852/what-is-the-best-apache-logs-analyzer) which could help you  on your way. This will help verify if google analytics is doing something wrong.

I've personally got real doubts with the effectiveness of "cold calling" email marketing. I don't think I've ever tried a website for the first time as a result of an email.

In terms of the sites I help look after, the newer sites are close to 95% search engine driven, the longer the domain has been around the lower this number drops. Even with 6 year old domains its still > 70%